# How would one prove that this algorithm to find connected dots works and converges?

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification

Consider a finite set $S_0$ of finite sets. Assume also that each element $s^0_i \in S_0$ does not have repeated elements, in case you think of $s^0_i$ as a vector (i.e: $s^0_i = (1, 1, 0) \notin  S_0$).

Take, for instance:
$$ S_0 = \{(1, 2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (6)\} $$

The solution would be $P = \{\{(1, 2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)\}; \{6\}\}$

This is a graph theory problem, coming from a programming issue that I had. I first wanted to write code in `R` that would create a partition $P$ such that each set $P_q$ in it would only elements $s^0_i, s^0_j \in S$ such that $s^0_i \cap s^0_j \neq \emptyset$ or such that $s_i \cap s^0_k \neq \emptyset, s^0_i \cap s^0_k \neq \emptyset $ for some $s^0_k \in P_q$ - Basically, I wanted to group connected elements in $S_0$.

The solutions in R were not really efficient so that I thought of the following algorithm:

1. Let $S = \bigcup_i s^0_i$. For every $s^0_i = \{s^0_{i1}, s^0_{i2}, \dots, s^0_{iJ_i}\}$, take the most common $s^0_{ij}$ in $S$. If there is a tie between two or more elements, take the smallest one. Call them $h_{i}$.
2. Now form $H_1 = \{h_1, h_2, \dots, h_I\}$.
3. Create set $S_1 =\{s^1_i, \dots s^1_I\}$ so that, if $h_i = h_j$, then $s^1_i = \dots = s^1_j = \bigcup_{k \in \{i, \dots, j\}}s^0_k$.

Go back to step 1 and continue until $S_n$ is constant in $n$.

How would one prove that this algorithm works in the sense that $S_n$ always converges to the desired partition $P$?

I do not know anything about graph or group theories, it was only a solution that seemed to work for every example I've created. I gladly accept proofs considering only $s_i \in \mathbb R^{n_i}$ that do not rely on graph or group theories.

Answer (score 0):

First off, this is indeed a graph theory problem in disguise. Construct a graph $G$ with vertex set $S_0$ such that two vertices $s_i^0, s_j^0 \in S_0$ are adjacent if and only if their intersection is nonempty. Then what you're looking for are the [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)) of $G$. There are efficient and simple algorithms for finding the connected components of a graph using, for example, [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

There are multiple things in your algorithm that I don't understand. First off, you say that the elements of $S_0$ are sets, but then write its elements as vectors. What is, then, the union of two vectors? For the moment I'll assume that they are indeed just sets. Then if we start from $S_0 = \{\{1,2\},\{2\}\}$, we obtain $H_1 = \{1,2\}$ and then it seems to me that $S_1$ will be just $S_0$ again.

Comment: On your example, H1 should be { (2) , (1,2)}. Maybe I've used the wrong words in that h would be the most common element  considering all entries of S_0

Comment: Oh, you're right, I misread it. But why do you write $h_2 = (1,2)$?

Comment: Oh, now I've miswritten it haha, it should be $h_2 = \{2\}$

Comment: It seems to me that what your algorithm does on the graph level is to (simultaneously) contract some edges in the graph in each step. This does not change the number of connected components. In the end, the graph will be made up of isolated vertices, each vertex corresponding to a connected component of a graph.